# Having trouble with has_many/belongs_to relation and `can't write unknown attribute`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

The basic idea is this:  I have a `Board` class with two players and a current player.  I want to be able to do `@board.current_player` and have it return an instance of `Player`, whereas right now, it's set up so that `@board.current_player_id` returns the id of a player, and I have to query on that id to get the current_player.

Here are my classes

```
class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :player1, class_name: 'Player'
  has_one :player2, class_name: 'Player'
  has_one :current_player, class_name 'Player'
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :board
end
```

Here is the migration

```
class CreatePlayersAndBoard < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change 
    create_table :boards do |t|
      t.references :current_player, references: :players
    end

    create_table :players do |t|
      t.belongs_to :board, index: true
    end
  end 
end
```

as per the RailsGuides entry for the has_one association.

Both `@board.player1` and `@board.player2` return a player instance, but because the id for `current_player` lives on the `boards` table, it doesn't seem the `has_one|belongs_to` relationship is working out.

I'd love to understand what exactly it is that allows ActiveRecord to return an instance rather than an ID - I always thought it was either on one side of the ActiveRecord Association, or in the migration and I'm having trouble seeing exactly where.

Perhaps this is an anti-pattern and I should store the logic for determining current player elsewhere, but after some thought this still feels like the correct placement.

Answer (score 1):

In your Board model you have `has_one :current_player` so when you do this it will run query like this.

```
irb(main):008:0> board.current_player
Player Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "players".* FROM "players" WHERE "players"."board_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["board_id", 1]]
```

if you want to keep current_player_id in your board table then you will have to do something like this

```
class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :player1, class_name: 'Player'
  has_one :player2, class_name: 'Player'

  def current_player
    Player.find(current_player_id)
  end
end
```